# Here Maps: Find Sequence API: HTTP 429 Too Many Requests even on one or two requests

Tags: authentication, here-api

Here Maps Find Sequence API hits HTTP 429 Too Many Requests even if we use the API for like once in a while. I have set up back off and it still doesn't seem to work.

API URL: https://wse.ls.hereapi.com/2/findsequence.json

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: I hosted my own routing engine with OSRM. They have a docker image to simplify things.